# Ambiguities regarding templated specialization for a deserializer's pop function

Tags: c++

I have a queue of serialized objects which I want to deserialize.
I deserialize the objects in the same order they were serialized.
The objects can be a variety of types including strings, structs and vectors which works.
The issue is that I am looking for a mainstream method of popping my deserialized elements.
I'm not happy having to deal with:

```
int ex1 = deserializer.pop<int>();
box_t ex2 = deserializer.pop<box_t>();
std::string ex2 = deserializer.popString();
std::vector<float> ex3 = deserializer.popVector<float>();
```

I would like to do.

```
int ex1 = deserializer.pop<int>();
box_t ex2 = deserializer.pop<box_t>();
std::string ex3 = deserializer.pop<std::string>();
std::vector<float> ex4 = deserializer.pop<std::vector<float>>();
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
template<typename Test, template<typename...> class Ref>
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename...> class Ref, typename... Args>
struct is_specialization<Ref<Args...>, Ref> : std::true_type {};

template<typename data_t>
data_t pop()
{
    if (is_specialization<data_t, std::vector>::value) {
        std::vector<issue1> data = deserialize_vector();
        return data; // issue2
    } else if ((is_specialization<data_t, std::string>::value)) {
        std::string data = deserialize_string();
        return data; // issue2
    } else {
        return deserialize<data_t>();
    }
}
```

issue1: how can I determine vector's data type?
issue2: the compiler won't return an explicitly defined type.
Is it even possible to implement in one function?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good use case for tag-dispatching. Use helper functions to overload based on the type provided, and call the specialized `deserialize` functions for those types. A helper `type_t` tag type can be used to hold the type, it also makes for a cleaner interface.

```c++
namespace impl {
  template<class T> struct type_t { using type=T; };

  template<class T>
  T pop( type_t<T> ) {
    return deserialize<T>();
  }

  template<class T>
  std::vector<T> pop( type_t<std::vector<T>> ) {
    return deserialize_vector();
  }

  std::string pop( type_t<std::string> ) {
    return deserialize_string();
  }
}
```

Then in your outer `pop`:

```c++
template<typename data_t>
data_t pop() {
  return impl::pop( impl::type_t<data_t>{} );
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, I never considered such a paradigm. This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> how can I determine vector's data type?

You might use `typename data_t::value_type`.

> the compiler won't return an explicitly defined type. Is it even possible to implement in one function?

If you have access to C++17, you might simply change your `if` by `if constexpr` (as your conditions are compile time):

```
template<typename data_t>
data_t pop()
{
    if constexpr (is_specialization<data_t, std::vector>::value) {
        std::vector<issue1> data = deserialize_vector();
        return data;
    } else if constexpr (is_specialization<data_t, std::string>::value) {
        std::string data = deserialize_string();
        return data;
    } else {
        return deserialize<data_t>();
    }
}
```

Prior to C++17 (and even with C++17), tag dispatching is a good way to fix your issue.

SFINAE would be an other approach, but seems more complicated in your case.